# Как настроить подключение к удаленному docker хосту?

Tags: docker, ssh, tls, x509certificate

Вот допустим поднят докер на сервере git.repo-test.com.
У меня на сервере имеется root доступ по ssh.

Дальше я экспортирую переменные:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="ssh://git.repo-test.com" DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Далее хочу посмотреть контейнеры:

```
docker ps
```

А в ответ докер выдает ошибку:

```
 /home/manking/.docker/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

Я так понимаю нужно указать путь к папке с сертификатами. И экспортировать переменную DOCKER_CERT_PATH?

Но вот где взять эти сертификаты? Их нужно генерировать локально или они должны быть уже на сервере и их нужно искать там?

---

После добавления своего pub ключа ssh в на сервер.  И удаления переменной DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY.
Команда

```
docker ps
```

выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Команда
docker-compose ps

```
docker-compose ps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 41, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 121, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 92, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 120, in docker_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 114, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 256, in parse_host
docker.errors.DockerException: Invalid bind address protocol: ssh://andryu@git.repo-test.com
[8063] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: Если есть доступ по ssh, можете подключаться без сертификатов. Уберите переменную DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY.

Comment: Пишет manking@git.repo-test.com: Permission denied (publickey,password). Но там мой локальный пользователь указан. А как указать пользователя 
у которого есть доступ по ssh?

Comment: Я это делаю так: в файле userdir/.ssh/config указываю конфигурацию ssh по шаблону, далее DOCKER_HOST="ssh://ssh-config-name"

Comment: А ну экспортировал переменную DOCKER_HOST с указанием пользователя, но там тоже самое выводится и не запрашивается пароль как если бы заходил по ssh. Плюс там еще написано проверить что установлен докер версии 18.09 или выше, а на хосте стоит 17.05.0-ce.

Comment: Кстати, доступ к докер-хосту по ssh возможен только с использованием ключей.

Comment: @Bakhuss
А как указать этот файл с конфигурацией? У меня там лежат только 3 файла. id_rsa id_rsa.pub и known_hosts.

Comment: @Bakhuss
Ну а ключи нужно брать с докер хоста или откуда?

Comment: У вас должно быть настроено подключение к серверу, на котором установлен докер, с использованием ключей, без пароля.

Comment: У меня есть доступ к серверу по ssh. С вводом пароля. Там стоит докер, есть какие то файлы сертификатов в разных папках.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115170/discussion-between-bakhuss-and-manking).

Comment: Видимо использовалась библиотека docker-machine. С помощью команды docker-machine create выполнилось подключение к удаленному серверу через ssh, и там были удалены все запущенные контейнеры и образы. Далее docker-machine сам создал и скопировал сертификаты на клиент и сервер. После этого стал работать docker и docker-compose на удаленном хосте локально.